# Results in descending order

Tags: c#

I've got a block of code which sums up time togged for various tasks in a project and returns the total hours logged per project (intMinutesLogged). How do I get my results n descending order?

```
static async void NotifyEntriesByWorkSpace(Dictionary<string, List<TimeEntry>> dicEntriesByWorkspace, string strChatURL)
{
    string strMessage = "";
    foreach (var kvpEntry in dicEntriesByWorkspace)
    {
        var lstTimeEntries = kvpEntry.Value;
        string strTitle = "";
        var intMinutesLogged = 0;
        var intMinutesBillable = 0;
        var intMinutesNonBillable = 0;

        foreach (var objTimeEntry in lstTimeEntries)
        {
            
            if (objTimeEntry.Billable)
            {

                intMinutesBillable += objTimeEntry.TimeInMinutes;
            }
            else
            {
                intMinutesNonBillable += objTimeEntry.TimeInMinutes;
            }
        }

        strTitle = Workspaces.getWorkspaceFromCache(kvpEntry.Key).Title;
        //Console.WriteLine(intMinutesLogged + ": " + strTitle + "m");
        intMinutesLogged = intMinutesBillable + intMinutesNonBillable;
        Console.WriteLine(TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesLogged) + ": " + strTitle + " " + "(Billable: " + TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesBillable) + ";" + " " + "Non-Billable: " + TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesNonBillable) + ")");
        strMessage += TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesLogged) + ": " + strTitle + " " + "(Billable: " + TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesBillable) + ";" + " " + "Non-Billable: " + TimeLoggedMessage(intMinutesNonBillable) + ")" + "\n";
       
    }

    await SendMessage(strChatURL, strMessage);
}

static string TimeLoggedMessage(int intMinutesLogged)
{
    return intMinutesLogged / 60 + "h" + " " + intMinutesLogged % 60 + "m";
}
```

Comment: Side note, if at all possible, avoid `async void` and prefer `async Task`.

Comment: `async void` is a bug here. It's *only* meant for asynchronous event handlers in older desktop stacks like WinForms or WPF, where the runtime know nothing about Tasks or how to await them. Use `async Task` for asynchronous methods that return no value

Comment: There's no `await` in this code, so `async` has no effect. The compiler probably generates a warning about this already

Comment: `await SendMessage(strChatURL, strMessage);` @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0

You could create a simple class or anonymous type to hold the integer values you're summing up (total minutes, billable minutes, non-billable minutes). Then you could populate a collection of this type within the code you shared and afterwards call OrderByDescending on it. You could order based on any of the three integer values.